# How can I bind tag id when convert Xml to Html with Xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I use XSLT while convert Xml to html. I need to bind value to h4 tag to generate bookmark, but I get xslt compile error. How can I achive this ?

```
<xsl:for-each select="checklist">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <h4 id=<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>'>
                      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </h4>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="tbChecklist">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="summary"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: you can see the part of xslt above

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say, can you show your input XML, as well as the output you expect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) here

```
<h4 id="{@value}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
</h4>
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.

Note that you can also use `xsl:attribute` to do this

```
<h4>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
</h4>
```

But as you can see, AVTs are much preferable.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your XSLT file isn't well formatted. One possible solution is using **xsl:attribute** element:

```
<h4>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
</h4>
```

Though it's not much elegant. Another different solution is using a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="value">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

And use it where necessary:

```
<h4 id="{$id}"><xsl:value-of select="$value"/></h4>
```